# Is there a way to decompress a Fody-Costura generated exe in c#?

Tags: decompress, c#, exe, windows-10, dnspy

There is a program that is possibly a RAT, and I would like to view the source code.
After opening the .exe in dnSpy, I was able to tell that it was compressed with Fody-Costura. (https://github.com/Fody/Costura)
Is there any way to de-compress the file? If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Embedded assemblies needs to be decompressed before they can be used so you can inspect all the code that does that in the assembly. Just go to `Costura.AssemblyLoader` to check how it is done. below is a extract from a simple example using `Costura.Fody`.

```
Assembly executingAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
if (fullName.EndsWith(".compressed"))
{
    using (Stream manifestResourceStream = executingAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(fullName))
    {
        using (DeflateStream deflateStream = new DeflateStream(manifestResourceStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            AssemblyLoader.CopyTo(deflateStream, memoryStream);
            memoryStream.Position = 0L;
            return memoryStream;
        }
    }
}
```

You could modify this code to save decompressed assemblies to disk by adding a line `File.WriteAllBytes(fullName.Replace(".compressed", ""), memoryStream.ToArray());` or just extract dlls resources and decompress externally via python or anything else that can do deflate.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply! How should I go about extracting the resources? I found a few resource extractors, but none of them seem to work.

Comment: dnSpy has an option to save reaources.

Answer (score 2):

I had success using the [Fody-Costura-Decompress tool](https://github.com/G4224T/Fody-Costura-Decompress).

You would need to build the solution from source. it has a simple GUI for choosing your file and decompressing it.